# How can I implement ocr react native . I have implemented it in android but it does not work in iOS

Tags: reactjs, iphone, react-native, software-design

https://github.com/ashrithks/rn-text-detector
https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector
These are the libraries I used while implementing my project.
It does not work in iOS but it works in android while implementing in iOS I got this error

CompileC /Users/Macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRANE-ciqqhizauxjmlaevomkjkiypelyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNTextDetector.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNTextDetector.o /Users/Macbook/Documents/GitHub/crane-app/CRANE/node_modules/rn-text-detector/ios/RNTextDetector.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNTextDetector' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

The code I used inside the

import RNTextDetector from "rn-text-detector";

const captureImage = async type => {
let options = {
mediaType: type,
maxWidth: 300,
maxHeight: 550,
quality: 1,
videoQuality: 'low',
durationLimit: 30, //Video max duration in seconds
saveToPhotos: true,
};
let isCameraPermitted = await requestCameraPermission();
let isStoragePermitted = await requestExternalWritePermission();
if (isCameraPermitted && isStoragePermitted) {
launchCamera(options, response => {
console.log('Response = ', response);

```
    if (response.didCancel) {
      alert('User cancelled camera picker');
      return;
    } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
      alert('Camera not available on device');
      return;
    } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
      alert('Permission not satisfied');
      return;
    } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
      alert(response.errorMessage);
      return;
    }
    console.log('base64 -> ', response.assets[0].base64);
    console.log('uri -> ', response.assets[0].uri);
    console.log('width -> ', response.assets[0].width);
    console.log('height -> ', response.assets[0].height);
    console.log('fileSize -> ', response.assets[0].fileSize);
    console.log('type -> ', response.assets[0].type);
    console.log('fileName -> ', response.assets[0].fileName);
    setFilePath(response.assets[0].uri);

    (async () => {

      const textRecognition = await RNTextDetector.detectFromUri(response.assets[0].uri);

      console.log('Base64_Image', textRecognition);
        setSerialNumber(textRecognition[0].text)

    })();

    RNFS.readFile(response.assets[0].uri, "base64").then(result => {
      // setSingleFileBase64('data:image/png;base64,' + result)

      setImage('data:/' + response.assets[0].type + ';' + 'base64,' + result)
      // console.log('Base64_Image', 'data:/'+response.assets[0].type+';'+'base64,' + result);
      setScreenData({ ...screenData, image1: 'data:/' + response.assets[0].type + ';' + 'base64,' + result });

    })

  });
}
```

};

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how to read a text from a image (OCR) in react native I tried many ways but doesn't work . it works fine in android but does't work in iOS